# Encrypted home with Ecryptfs - How to store the key file if i missed it on first boot?

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with encrypted Home-directory. When I first booted I was given the option to store a key file to some Flash-drive (USB) or anything and there was a hint how to do it later. I wanted to do it later but now can't find where to find or how to generate the key file in any documentation.

So whats the command, where's the file? Ecryptfs-manger only offers me to generate a new pair.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I happened to get the Message again now, after an update:

> Record your encryption passphrase
>
> To encrypt your home directory or "Private" folder, a strong
>   passphrase has been automatically generated. Usually your directory
>   is unlocked with your user password, but if you ever need to manually
>   recover this directory, you will need this passphrase. Please print
>   or write it down and store it in a safe location. If you click "Run
>   this action now", enter your login password at the "Passphrase" prompt
>   and you can display your randomly generated passphrase. Otherwise, you will need to run "ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase" from the command
>   line to retrieve and record your generated passphrase.

So `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the official docs here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ecryptfs.html

Check **Automatically Mounting Encrypted Partitions**